# How do I track a camera that moves a long distance (IE, a bike going down the side of an entire mountain), without losing accuracy?

Tags: motion-capture

I have a couple of videos I pulled off of youtube of bike runs down the sides of mountains, and I would like to digitally add in some crazy scenery as a joke like lava pits in the jumps, etc...

however, I keep running into a problem with my much simpler test footage (which is me walking through a long curved hallway in a first-person game), where I am able to get a perfect track (error less than half a pixel) with all the due manual work put in, but for some reason, the parallax between the footage and the 3d blender scene seems to get worse the longer I walked in the footage, even with the error maintained at a very low number.

my understanding of how blender's motion tracking works is that everything between the A and B keyframes is where the algorithm does all the actual calculations, and everything else is kind of just lazily extrapolated somehow.... if that's the case, is there a way for me to force blender to do the accurate calculations for the entire scene? or is there a way to perhaps do multiple camera tracks, and then align them perfectly with each other and link them together seamlessly?

I'm just looking for a way to track the whole scene from start to finish as the camera moves through it for a long distance, but every tutorial I see is just tracking a small area and hovering around the object, which is barely useful knowledge for anything more complex than that.

i am well aware that there's a similar question already posted here, but there is not enough information in the answer to really help me (I've tried it): [Tracking very long shot with no points in common between first and last frame](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80338/tracking-very-long-shot-with-no-points-in-common-between-first-and-last-frame)

Comment: Sorry, I'm really no expert at motion tracking. I was just wandering, if you say the parallax between footage and 3D scene gets worse - are you doing object motion tracking or camera motion tracking, to put it simple?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann camera. sorry if this wasnt clear